# Which all files inside the writeable folder in Codeigniter4 should I clear regularly?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

In Codeigniter4 application I found that there are so many unwanted files inside the `writable` folder like the contents of the `log` folder , the `debugbar` folder and the `session` folder. Can I clear the contents of these folder regularly which seems to get accumulated on continuous use.

Answer (score 0):

**The writable folder should only be used for temporary files**, so you could delete everything...globally. At least metadata, annotations, debugbar. The presence of debugbar indicates that you might still be in development (look in the .ENV file)?

That said, the best way would be to define a retention policy for your data, at least for your logs.
How long do you want to keep them?

Regarding the sessions, it is not normal that these are never erased. You should at least check their expiration or destroy them in your code. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences